# What will be the effect of adding compression in kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka

After implementation of gzip compression, whether messages stored earlier will aslo get compressed? And while sending messages to consumer whether Message content is changed or kafka internally uncompresses it?

Answer (score 2):

If you turn on Broker side compression, existing messages are unchanged. Compression will apply to only new messages. When consumers fetch the data, it will be automatically decompressed so you don't have to handle it on the consumer side. Just remember, there's a CPU and latency cost by doing this type of compression potentially.

Comment: So if i create new topic and start processing messages...those will be compressed?